# Mandelbrot plot error matplotlib python 3.4

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, mandelbrot

I am trying to to do a Mandelbrot plot for z′ = z^2 + c where c =x +iy on an N × N grid spanning the region where −2 ≤ x ≤ 2 and −2 ≤ y ≤ 2. and N =100. my ccom method is c =x +iy and my zcom method is for z^2 and my zprime method is for z' part i made recursive for a 100 iterations. But I am unsure why get back very large values for my zp array that zprime returns. I have tried to feed the arrays for imshow but it says invalid arguments.

**My Code:**

```
import math as mathy
import decimal as deci
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt


#z' = z**2 + c
#z=x+iy
#|z|<2
#c = x + iy
#−2 ≤ x ≤ 2,−2 ≤ y ≤ 2
#(x + iy)(u + iv)=(xu – yv) + (xu + yv)i

def zcom(u,v):


    zcsq = np.zeros(2,float)
    zcsq[0] = ((u)**2) - ((v)**2)

    zcsq[1] = ((u)**2) + ((v)**2)

    return zcsq

def ccom(x,y):

    cc = np.zeros(2,float)
    cc[0] = x
    cc[1]= y

    return cc

def zprime(u,v,x,y,n):
    zp = np.zeros((n,1,2),float)
    t1=np.linspace(-x,x,100)
    t2=np.linspace(-y,y,100)
    for i in range(0,n):

        zp[i] = zcom(u,v) + ccom(t1[i],t2[i])
        u= zp[i][0,0]
        v= zp[i][0,1]        
    return zp

plt.imshow(zprime(0,0,2,2,100), cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

**My Error:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "Mandelbrot.py", line 25
    zcsq[0] = ((u)**2) - ((v)**2)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "Mandelbrot.py", line 25
    zcsq[0] = ((u)**2) - ((v)**2)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "Mandelbrot.py", line 27
    zcsq[1] = ((u)**2) + ((v)**2)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "Mandelbrot.py", line 27
    zcsq[1] = ((u)**2) + ((v)**2)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mandelbrot.py", line 53, in <module>
    plt.imshow(zprime(0,0,2,2,100), cmap='hot')
  File "matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2892, in imshow
    imlim=imlim, resample=resample, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "matplotlib\axes.py", line 7306, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "matplotlib\image.py", line 430, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that your code seems to show a slight misunderstanding of the Mandelbrot set.

When you do the iteration to form the set, the result of the iteration is either bounded or unbounded.  **The Mandelbrot set is all of the iterations that are bounded**, and the starting points that lead to unbounded results are not part of the set.

Usually, to yield a pretty result, the starting points that are not part of the set are plotted based on how many iterations it took to decide that the iteration was unbounded.  (Hopefully, it's obvious at this point why you get the overflow, because "unbounded" can lead to very big result, in this case of 100 iterations, on the order of 2<sup>2<sup>100</sup></sup>, which is a very big number, but to know that the result will be unbounded, you can just stop when the value is greater than 2.)

Below is the result and the code I used, based on your code.  The main important change was in the loop, I checked whether the iteration ever produced a result greater than 2, and if it did I noted the iteration number (just to give the color, though this point is not in the set), and if it never got greater than 2, I set the value to 0, and this point is in the set (to within the accuracy of the calculation and number of iterations).  I thought it was easier to keep things in complex number notation, but you can change it back if you like.  I also removed the functions for clarity.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

def zprime(x,y,n):
    t1=np.linspace(-x,x,1000)
    t2=np.linspace(-y,y,1000)
    result = np.zeros((len(t1),len(t2)), np.int) # make a result array that matches the x,y grid, since you want an image of the x,y grid
    for i, u0 in enumerate(t1):
        for j, v0 in enumerate(t2):
            z0 = u0 + 1j*v0 # initial value for iteration
            zp = 1.*z0   # just a copy, ie, the value of the first iteration
            for k in range(1,n):  # starting from 1, since the first was a copy (I'm not saying this detail is important, just how I think of it)
                zp = zp**2 + z0 # the defining calculation
                if abs(zp)>2.: # >2 means unbounded, so not in the M-set
                    result[i, j] = k  # set the result to k just to give some color
                    break
            else: # never hit a break, so this point is in the M-set
                result[i, j] = 0
    return result

mset = zprime(2,2,50)
plt.imshow(mset, cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much two questions one is z just z' squared ? Two how did you get the imshow to display I tired feeding it arrays but it would say invalid dimensions. And again thanks a lot I was trying to fix this for hours but got frustrated and posted it.

Comment: For your second question: the shape of my returned array (`result`) is (1000,1000), and yours (`zp`) is `(n, 1, 2)`.  `imshow` wants a NxN array, so the shape you had won't work.  For your first question, I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I think the answer is "no, but almost".   In the iteration, the n+1th value of `z` is `z0` (often called `c`) plus the square of the nth value of z, ie, `zp = zp**2 + z0` as I have in the code.